# Validate a condition that relies on foreign keys in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-validation

I have two models, `Book` and `Page`, where `Page` has a foreign key relation to `Book`. In admin.py, the webpage to modify a book has inline elements for `Page` objects.

models.py:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    # ...

class Page(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, editable=False)
    number = models.IntegerField('Page number')
    # ...
```

admin.py:

```
class PageAdminInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Page
    extra = 1

class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PageAdminInline]

admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
```

In the inline forms, a field allows to set the page number for each page. With this configuration, how can I validate the global condition that all pages numbers of a book should be different and numbered from one to the number of `Page` objects associated to the book?

I suppose I have to override a `clean()` method related to a book model or form somewhere, but I don't know how to access from there the data related to the pages that the user inputs.

**Edit**

Based on Emett's suggestion, I have tried to override the `clean()` method of the `Page` model:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, editable=False)
    number = models.IntegerField('Page number')

    def clean():
        book_pages = Page.objects.filter(book=self.book)
        # ... [apply condition on the book_pages QuerySet]
        super(Page, self).clean()
```

This does not work: if I modify the page number of all pages in the admin site for a book, `book_pages` will contain objects that have the old page numbers.

In addition, having the condition checked in `Page` also means that it  will be tested n times if I have n pages, while just checking it once should be sufficient.

Comment: This needs to be done in your `models.py`. Could you please provide the models?

Comment: @EmettSpeer Are you sure? In models.py, I would need to access in a ``Book`` method instances of ``Page`` objects that are not saved to the database at the time of the validation.

Comment: You require that the page have a book attached to it when you save a new page in the database. This would be the right time to have the system preform this logic. It seems like `unique-together` would be the right option for this problem. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#unique-together

Comment: Thanks, I will see if I can make it work by changing the ``Page`` model. unique-together looks like a very good suggestion. However, the book-page problem is just an example, and the condition I want to validate is more complex than just having different page numbers!

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution would be putting unique_together in django model. IE

```
class Page(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, editable=False)
    number = models.IntegerField('Page number')

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'page'
        db_table = 'pages'
        verbose_name = 'Page'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Pages'
        unique_together = (('book', 'number'),)
```

Another workaround if you don't want to use `unique_together`, then create a form, use it in inline, ie:

```
class PageForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
     model = Page
     fields ='__all__'

   def clean():
       cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
       book = cleaned_data.get('book')
       number = cleaned_data.get('number')
       page_qset = Page.objects.filter(book=book, number=number)

       if len(page_qset) > 0:  # inefficient solution, using it for forcibly executing query
             raise forms.ValidationError('Already exists')
       return super().clean()



class PageAdminInline(admin.TabularInline):
    form = PageForm
```

Comment: unique checking is built into model forms. So you don't need that customized clean method

Comment: Its a workaround if model does not have `unique_together` :)

Comment: Ah re reading your answer again, I see what you mean. Your first suggestion using a unique together is an excellent one. Constraints should always be implemented at the database level. The approach in the original question and in your form is actually a very bad idea. It's reinventing the wheel to  begin with. Except that the wheel we have is an alloy wheel with low profile tires. And it does nothing to tackle race conditions

Comment: @e4c5 I agree. `unique_together` is the best solution

Comment: @ruddra I just tried your solution. I run into the same problem as in what I tried in the edited part of my question. At your line ``Page.objects.filter(book=book, number=number).exists()``, the QuerySet contains Page objects that have the old page numbers, and not the new ones I inputted in the form.

Comment: And don't focus too much on ``unique_together`` :-) The condition I have to satisfy on the related instances is actually more complex than the simple example in the question, which makes ``unique_together`` innapropriate.

Comment: @mimo you can forcibly execute queryset by calling `len(queryset)`, please check my updated answer please